# How to send SMS from Android emulator to a phone using GSM modem?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is it possible to send SMS from Android emulator to a mobile phone via a GSM modem connected to a USB port of computer ? If it is possible how can I do that

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could do that but android won't detect it as a native antena, in other word, all functions from android to send sms or initiate a call won't work.

If the device is visible is /dev/.. You could be able to open it and send command trough serial. Unless someone wrote a driver so android can load it for gsm communication inside the emulator, my guess is that it's pretty useless.

Anyway, the emulator does have a way to test sms sending as far as I can remember, and if you really want to send sms trough your gsm dongle, It's probably a better idea to start writing a script using python for example. There is also a library that enable sms sending from linux, it might also work on other platforms.

**Sending sms from python from computer:**
http://designbuildtestrepeat.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/sms-over-3g-and-bluetooth-from-python/

**Checking incoming sms for emulator android:**
http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/

**Sending sms between emulators:**
http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/sending-messages-among-devices/

And then it really depends on what you need. You didn't exactly said why you wanted to do that. You didn't say if you wanted to test sms messaging or wanted to send actual sms from computer. It's not really clear why you need android and the gsm modem at the same time.